# skip files while creating or updating the view in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

I am trying to create/update view using ClearCase, but while downloading it gets struck and exits without creating the full view.
Is there any workaround to either skip the files and download manually?

Please suggest.

[image: Error]

[image: Error Stack]

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot that kind of error message, it can be helpful to reproduce the [snapshot view update](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_update_files_ssv.htm) in [command line](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_load_unload_ssv.htm) to see if any other error message pops up ([`cleartool update`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)).

```
cd C:\CCSS1\UT_ISR
cleartool update -print -log C:\temp\log.txt .
```

If it is not a [path length issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117876), check if the view storage path is accessible (the one starting with `\\...` redacted in the pictures)

Check the characteristics of that view

```
cd C:\CCSS1\UT_ISR
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

Check the logs:

```
cleartool getlog -last 20 view
```

Check if the issue persists after reboot (in case a process might currently keep an handle on a resource which would then be blocked and updated)

The [OP dodger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3360630/dodger) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998082/skip-files-while-creating-or-updating-the-view-in-clearcase/38001110?noredirect=1#comment63449194_38001110):

> I was able to overcome the problem by downloading files that were only pertinent and rest I skipped.

Comment: I was able to overcome the problem by downloading files that were only pertinent and rest I skipped.Thanks a lot, though...

Comment: @dodger OK, I have included your workaround in the answer for more visibility.